# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Error global.asax

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 I get the following error in all (5) of my existing ASP.NET MVC 5 projects.

I even tried creating a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project but get the same error! Any suggestion?

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication7.MvcApplication'.
>
> Source Error:  Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication7.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
>
> Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

Comment: try to`right click your project title, in this case "WebApplication7" and click build.`

Comment: It compiles OK but I cannot run (F5) from Visual Studio 2015 not even a new project. 
MVC 6 projects works fine.

Comment: try to uncheck the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" under the debug tab in the project properties

Answer (score 1):

100% working

1. Delete the Global.asax file  and add it again.
   2.Now build your website and run it.
   It will be worked.........